# CONSECUTIVE DAYS QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image: DB SAMPLE]

I have an Oracle DB Connection that has data (SELECT * FROM SALES) as in the picture, i want a query that gives me which 3 consecutive days are those who have the sum of PREMIUM_TOTAL > 100.
I have tried with the method lead, lag , DATADIFF but failed. Also i'm new at this,  if you can give me hints please.

Comment: Define "failed".  `datediff` isn't a function that exists in Oracle.  You could have implemented one to be compatible with some other database like SQL Server that has that as a built-in.  But I don't know if you did.  Show us a reproducible example and tell us what isn't working (syntax error?  incorrect results?  Something else?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want 3 rows from successive days then you can use a recursive query:

```sql
WITH successive_days (day, products, total, depth) AS (
  SELECT entry_date,
         TO_CHAR(product_id),
         premium_total,
         1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT s.day + 1,
         s.products || ',' || t.product_id,
         s.total + t.premium_total,
         s.depth + 1
  FROM   successive_days s
         INNER JOIN table_name t
         ON (s.day + 1 = t.entry_date)
  WHERE  s.depth < 3
)
SELECT day AS final_day, products, total
FROM   successive_days
WHERE  depth = 3
AND    total >= 100;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (product_id, entry_date, premium_total) AS
SELECT  1, DATE '2022-03-01',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, DATE '2022-03-01',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, DATE '2022-03-02',  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, DATE '2022-03-03',  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2022-03-21',  12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2022-03-31',  40.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, DATE '2022-03-05',  70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, DATE '2022-03-05',  80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, DATE '2022-03-05',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, DATE '2022-03-06',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, DATE '2022-03-07',  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, DATE '2022-03-07',  40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, DATE '2022-03-08',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 31, DATE '2022-03-09',  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 40, DATE '2022-03-10',   2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FINAL_DAY | PRODUCTS | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 13,20,21 | 120 |
> | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 13,20,22 | 130 |
> | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 12,20,21 | 130 |
> | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 12,20,22 | 140 |
> | 2022-03-09 00:00:00 | 21,30,31 | 100 |
> | 2022-03-09 00:00:00 | 22,30,31 | 110 |

---

If you want all the rows (at least 3) that are all within 3 successive days then you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(entry_date) AS start_day,
       MAX(entry_date) AS final_day,
       LISTAGG(product_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY entry_date) AS products,
       SUM(premium_total) AS total
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY entry_date
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
  PATTERN (first_day+ second_day+ third_day* final_day)
  DEFINE
    first_day  AS FIRST(entry_date) = entry_date,
    second_day AS FIRST(entry_date) + 1 = entry_date,
    third_day  AS FIRST(entry_date) + 2 = entry_date,
    final_day  AS FIRST(entry_date) + 2 = entry_date
               AND SUM(premium_total) >= 100
)
GROUP BY mno;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | START_DAY | FINAL_DAY | PRODUCTS | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-05 00:00:00 | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 12,13,14,20,21,22 | 250 |
> | 2022-03-05 00:00:00 | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 13,14,20,21,22 | 170 |
> | 2022-03-05 00:00:00 | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 13,20,21,22 | 160 |
> | 2022-03-06 00:00:00 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | 20,21,22,30 | 110 |
> | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 2022-03-09 00:00:00 | 21,22,30,31 | 140 |
> | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 2022-03-09 00:00:00 | 22,30,31 | 110 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c6a48b159610f33461f80e70607e0b1f)*